# How to use github library in android studio

Tags: android, github

I am trying to use this ExtendedCalendarView from github: https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView but I am not clear on how to add this to my android studio project. I tried to create a libs folder in my project folder and then pulled to the libs folder. Then I tried to sync the project but it did not work.

Comment: The `ExtendedCalendarView` directory in that repository is an Android library project. You will need to clone this repository (or download the ZIP archive), so that entire `ExtendedCalendarView` directory is on your development machine. Then, try New > Import Module... from the Android Studio main menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they not offer gradle support, you need to download their library, and import it in Android Studio.

Do to this :

- Go to File -> Project Structure
- Then click the green + icon on the upper-left of the new window that just popped.
- Choose Phone and Tablet application, and "Import existing Eclipse ADT or Gradle project as a module".
- Select the library folder (the ExtendedCalendarView folder containing the AndroidManifest.xml folder), click Ok Next and Finish.
- Wait for gradle project to sync
- Then click on your main project module (often called "app"), and click on the upper-RIGHT green + icon, choose module dependency and select the  extendedCalendarView module we just created. Then click Ok.
- Wait for gradle project to sync

And you're good to go, your library is imported.

But, the library does not compile, you will see this error :

```
 Error:(11, 9) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:9
    is also present at XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:extendedCalendarView:unspecified:13:9 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5 to override
```

To fix it :

- Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to your AndroidManifest file, in the manifest element, next to your existing `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
- Then add `tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"` to your < application > element as the error message suggest.

Now the project compiles correctly !

Please ask me if you need any explanation or help.

Comment: Thank you Victor for all of your help! I am running into the compile error you mentioned. In my AndroidManifest file do I add xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" directly next to the first xmlns? For the second bullet poing in the "to fix it" what do you mean by my "element"?

Comment: I updated my response, <application> did not show up because of the stackoverflow text system that I don't master yet. I added spaces so that you can see it. For the manifest element, it should look like this : <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="net.victorleduc.testapp">

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning the library onto your computer then adding it as a module in Android Studio. Once you have completed that go to project settings and add the module as a dependency.